# Upgrading umbraco 4.11 to 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have an umbraco WebForms projects built on 4.11.10 that we need to upgrade to 7.3.8.

We have tools such as RedGate Data Compare and RedGate Structure Compare, but without firsthand knowledge of the new structure and how that has affected the way that data is stored we're finding it impossible to upgrade the database.

Does anyone know of a SQL script or tool that will upgrade just the database to the new format?

Thanks in advance for your time.
dotdev

Answer (score 1):

Recent changes in 7.3 greatly improved the experience (and success) of upgrading from older versions.

> Incredible engineering by the Umbraco core team, the new installer
>   just upgraded a 4,5 year old v4.7.1 db to v7.3 flawlessly #h5yr

https://twitter.com/umbraco/status/643721449295974401

This [blog post](http://www.attackmonkey.co.uk/blog/2015/10/upgrading-to-73) contains some more details on performing an upgrade from 4.7.1 to 7.3.